# How do I validate each row for a dynamically created table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, dynamic

I would like to validate each select option for each row of my dynamically created table.

I tried to do a for loop but it is only getting the value of the first row. Here is my code:

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var table = document.getElementById('criteriatbl');
    for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        var strRes = results.options[results.selectedIndex].text;
        alert(strRes);
    }
}
```

html table

```
<table border="1" width="" id='criteriatbl'>
        $i = 0;
        foreach($result as $criteria) {
            $i+=1;
           echo 
           "
            <tr><td align='center'>$i</td>
                <td align='center'> <label for='criteria'> $criteria->catID </label></td>
                <td>$criteria->category</td>
                <td style='word-wrap: break-word'>$criteria->critDesc</td>
                <td><select id='results' name='results[]'> 
                <option value='Select'>Select</option>
                <option value='Compliant'>Compliant</option>
                <option value='OFI'>OFI</option>
                <option value='AOC'>AOC</option>
                <option value='MinorNC'>Minor NC</option>
                <option value='MajorNC'>Major NC</option>
                <option value='NA'>NA</option>
                </select> </td>
                <td> <textarea name='comment[]' value='comment' rows='7' cols='45' placeholder='write something here'></textarea></td></tr>
            ";

        }
?>
            </table>
```

At each row I should be getting the value of each of the selected option by the user.

Comment: You can't use an exact same id within the same HTML code. As you have used the same id `results` more than once, JavaScript/jQuery can only take the first one. It will not look for another `results` on your HTML as an id should be unique

Comment: do you know any other ways to validate a select option in each row?

Comment: @blueKingdom11 you can create different id for each row, like this ( in HTML): <select id='results_<?php echo $i; ?>'  name='results[]'>   In JS you need to change like this : document.getElementById("results" + r);

Comment: from my code above, i changed to <select id='results_$i' name='results[]'> and JS to var results = document.getElementById("results" + i); however the value still does not display.